# DBChart and float-fields precision

Tags: delphi, decimal, precision, teechart

i have a database which is the source for DBChart. The problem is that DBChart plots graphic of raw floats (15 numbers), thus it looks very raggy. I tried to change TFloatField's both Precision and DisplayFormat, but it didn't help.

I would like to have big precision in database, so user can choose it himself when drawing graphic. Thus it would be unpleasant to cut floats before insertion.

Can you advice me something please?

Answer (score 1):

TeeChart Pro source code customers can change "Value" type for point values data between: Single, Double and Extended modifying TeeDefs.inc as explained [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12368&p=53309&#p53309).

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but this is not exactly what i mean. I will try to explain more carefully: there are float values in database like "29.43235". I wonder if there a possibility in TDBChart to choose values to plot, i.e. "29.4" or "29.43", so on. Currently my DBChart plots graphic with full precision.

Comment: You could cast your values before adding them to the series. To do it, you have to loop your tables manually or change how TeeChart does it if you have the sources.

Comment: You can also set series' values format using Series.ValueFormat property and also set how values are displayed in axis labels with Chart1.Axes.Bottom.AxisValuesFormat property.